# How to pass a span tag with id and class in MVCContrib grid

Tags: mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

In my application I have a column called "comments", in that I want to reestrict the characters to 54 and then append it with ellipses (i.e I really like your product ...) and having a jquery qtip on ... to show entire text on tooltip.

When I use the code

column.For(a => (
           ((a.Comments.Length > 54) ? (a.Comments.Substring(0, 53) + MvcHtmlString.Create("...").ToHtmlString()): MvcHtmlString.Create(a.Comments).ToHtmlString())

```
        )).HeaderAttributes(width => "40%").Named("Comment");
```

It prints Span id=".. also , it takes it as  a text.

Is there any way I can have a span in text which renders as HTML ??

Answer (score 0):

I've not used qtip, but generally if you want to use html in the mvccontrib grid, you use
`.DoNotEncode()`.